# Exporting Illustrator project to AE

Tags: vector, adobe-after-effects

I am trying to make extruded 3D layers of a logo In AE CC 2017. when I import a project from Illustrator CC 2017, place it on the timeline and select "Create shapes from vector layer", it creates a grey rectangle. There is no opacity on any layer in the Illustrator project and none in AE. The layers in Illustrator came from a Photoshop project,Any ideas on what's causing my results?
[image: Illustrator project]

[image: AE project]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is not vector but raster. To use "Create shapes from vector layer" in AE, you need a vector, otherwise it should make the shape (rectangle) of size of the image. To make it vector, you can trace it manually or use Image Trace tool in Illustrator.